# Batch script: assign variable from ethernet adapters list

Tags: batch-file, ethernet

Info: some of our colleges use a network USB adapter that registers as "Ethernet 3"
I need a way to determine if "Ethernet" or "Ethernet 3" is plugged in and set it as a variable, so I can execute a change ip. (Batch script)

```
netsh int ip set address "%Ethernet adapter%" static 192.168.0.186 255.0.0.0 192.168.0.1 1
```

Comment: Welcome as a new user to [SO]. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. Before asking a question you should do research on your issue, there are several questions with promising answers to find easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test if an internet is connected by using `FOR /F` & `netsh interface show interface^|find "Connected"`. This will search for all connected networks to your device.

From here we can use `echo %%B | findstr "Wi-Fi" > Nul` to filter the result's down to the `Wi-Fi` and use `IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0` to tell if it exists or not (Thus telling us if its online or not)

```
FOR /F "tokens=3,*" %%A IN ('netsh interface show interface^|find "Connected"') DO echo %%B | findstr "Wi-Fi" > Nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (GOTO :CONNECTED) ELSE (GOTO :DISCONNECTED)
```

Not sure if you need both to be connected or not due to your lack of description, but to do this you change the `(GOTO :CONNECTED) ELSE (GOTO :DISCONNECTED)` to variables (**example:**  `(SET C1=ONLINE) ELSE (SET C1=OFFLINE)`) and stack a new `FOR /F` for the next network. Then using an `IF /I ""==""` statement, you can compare the variables to see if both are "Online".

```
IF /I "%C1%"=="ONLINE" (IF /I "%C2%"=="ONLINE" (GOTO :ONLINE) ELSE (GOTO :OFFLINE)) ELSE (GOTO :OFFLINE)
```

Be sure to use the following command to find the **Interface Name** of your network for the `findstr` command.

`netsh interface show interface`

Comment: Thx I got it working now!